# Custom UINavigationController init results in use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have these custom classes :

1.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

}
```

2.

```
class HomeNavigationController: MyNavigationController {

    init() {
        super.init(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

3.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

4.

```
class HomeViewController: MyViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: .main)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Then I try to initialize an instance of `HomeNavigationController` in app delegate :

```
let homeVC = HomeNavigationController()
```

But when doing so, I get this error:

> fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'HomeNavigationController'

I don't see why it's trying to call it... so what to do?

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028940/mandatory-init-override-in-swift-uinavigationcontroller-subclass

Comment: [This will helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45228865/7576100)